# How to call a method from a class with inheritence on an object of the base class?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two classes. One inherits the other:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute = 1

class B(A):
    def get_attribute(self):
        return self.attribute
```

I would like to be able to call methods from B on objects of type A. I cannot edit class A (it is a built in class). When I try to call a method from B, there is an AttributeError.

```
a = A()
a.get_attribute()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    a.get_attribute()
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

Is there a way to call methods from B without explicitly declaring the data to be of type B?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? `A`, the superclass has no idea that, `B`, a subclass has some function

Comment: This is exactly the opposite of how inheritance works,so no, you can't do that.

Comment: "I would like to be able to call methods from B on objects of type A." - that fundamentally doesn't make sense. You might want to instead make this method an ordinary function, if it does something that makes sense for A objects and only uses functionality supported by A objects.

Comment: @AndrewL, A is a builtin class (say `str`). It's a bit inefficient to type out the type change every time I want to use that data type.

Comment: @cat40 But you do understand you're trying to achieve something fundamentally impossible and something that makes no sense?

Comment: @AndrewL I do now

Answer (score 0):

While it is discouraged to do you can use any method like a function. In your case it would be

```
B.get_attribute(a)
```

Of cause the method has to be compatible with the type of `a`.